# YouTube Embed into WordPress - Height problems

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, youtube

Trying to embed YouTube videos into a post. But for some idea the height get's really high. Setting height to `auto` or `100%` does not solve the problem.

I have already set the `width` to `100%`, so that the width is responsive and works fine. But the height is still the same for mobile, tablet and desktop. Meaning there will be a black bar below and above the movie.

Any ideas?

Please see: http://higraf.no/nyheter/finner-reklamehuset-higraf/

The video at the top is embedded with WP Types.

```
<?php $renderfieldmedia = types_render_field('film-nyheter', array('raw'=>'true'))?>
<?php if(!empty($renderfieldmedia)){?>
     <div id="videoholder">
           <?php echo(types_render_field('film-nyheter', array("output" => "html", "autoplay" => 1))); ?>
     </div>
<?php } elseif(empty($renderfieldmedia)){?>     
     <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail('full-hd'); } ?>
<?php }?>
```

The video at the bottom is the regular WordPress embedding with pasting the YouTube-link in the text field.

Questions? Please ask.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an iFrame so the best way is to set a static dimension to the video.

Something like:

```
.embed-container iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
}
```

Otherwise you can see [Bootstrap Responsive Embed](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#responsive-embed)

Comment: Tried to add the Bootstrap Responsive Embed, but this only made a white field, and no videos are being embedded.

Comment: So it's sure you made something wrong with the implementation ;)

Comment: Hehe. I guess...

However, this also shows only a white field, and no video:
`<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                            <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HHHnlF4JRqk"></iframe>
                        </div>`